# Como ejecutar un WS desde un .bat

Tags: genexus

Como puedo correr un web services con parámetros dentro en un .bat, lo puedo correr en el navegador sin problema pero necesito que corra en automático una vez al dia

Comment: Recuerda que puedes obtener ayuda y buenas respuestas agregando mayor información a tu pregunta, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando Curl podes ejecutar web service.
Por ejemplo:

```
curl -X GET "URL_DEL_WEBSERVICE" -o output.txt
```

Donde se consume tipo GET y la respuesta la escribe en el archivo output.txt